# Swift 3 - Balancing an Array

Tags: arrays, swift3, swift-playground

I am trying to balance an array in swift 3 Playgrounds.

Can anyone tell me why the console is printing 0 for myBalancePoint instead of 8, which represents myFirstArray[4]

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit

var divSum = Int()
var myBalancePoint = Int()
let myFirstArray = [1, 2, 5, 8, 4, 4]
divSum = myFirstArray.reduce(0, {$0 + $1}) / 2

print(divSum)

let firstPoint = myFirstArray[0]
print (firstPoint)

let secondPoint = myFirstArray[0] + myFirstArray[1]
print (secondPoint)

let thirdPoint = myFirstArray[0] + myFirstArray[1] + myFirstArray[2]
print (thirdPoint)

let fourthPoint = myFirstArray[0] + myFirstArray[1] + myFirstArray[2] + myFirstArray[3]
print (fourthPoint)

let fifthPoint = myFirstArray[0] + myFirstArray[1] + myFirstArray[2] +  myFirstArray[3] + myFirstArray[4]
print (fifthPoint)

let sixthPoint = myFirstArray[0] + myFirstArray[1] + myFirstArray[2] +  myFirstArray[3] + myFirstArray[4] + myFirstArray[5]
print (sixthPoint)


if fourthPoint > divSum {
    let myBalancePoint = myFirstArray[4]
}
print (myBalancePoint)
```

Comment: It printed out this `var myBalancePoint = Int()` not this `let myBalancePoint`

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped, but not completely. Now, the console prints 4, which is the index number for myFirstArray[4] . I am trying to get the console to print the 8, which is the value that index. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Never mind, it should print 4 because myFirstArray[4] has a value of 4. Whereas, myFirstArray[3] has the value of 8. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
if fourthPoint > divSum {
     myBalancePoint = myFirstArray[4]
}
print (myBalancePoint)
```

In if condition scope, you defined a new constant `let myBalancePoint` so that the value of `var myBalancePoint = Int()` not be changed.